# Can't inflate a textview from a resource file thats not the same as my activity

Tags: android, xml

I have a starting activity and im trying to use a separate textview as a footer when i implement a listview.

My app crashes every time i try to initialize it which is this way

```
TextView add;

add = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.tvAdd, null);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, AddToDoActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, GET_RESULT);
        }
    });
```

I have my add as a global variable at the top of my class.

The resource file connected with this activity is called activity_start.xml but the resource file for the textview is called footerview.xml, aka different resource files.

the footerview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add New To Do Item"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my starting xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.uilab.StartActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>


 </FrameLayout>
```

How can I add the textview to my activity?

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: If any of the answers have helped you, please accept the one that you ended up using as correct, otherwise lets figure out what isn't working. People here put in time to help you and the least you can do is accept the answer you ended up using, or at the very least, provide feedback of issues with any of the answers you are having.

Comment: @notrix I agree, it should work this way.

Comment: @user2981393 Did you read any of the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can only inflate layouts (-> xmls/R.layout.x) not single views inside any layout... so inflate your footerview.xml like:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.footerview, null);
```

and then access your textview using findViewById on that layout... but that won't add your view onto the activity layout...

i think you are looking for a way to include your footerview layout inside the activity_start layout... using the include-tag may help you with this (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)
you can then just access your textview with findViewById directly inside your activity

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity_start.xml` could be like my example below. There are both `ListView` and `TextView` in it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add New To Do Item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are doing all this in "onCreate" function of your activity, where you should be doing this). Ensure you inflate the main content first:

```
setContentView(R.layout.<"my starting xml" real file name>);
```

In order to add a footer to your ListView, you need to inflate the entire footer view (your footerview.xml) like so:

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footerview, null);
```

Keep track you your TextView:

```
TextView add = (TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.tvAdd);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, AddToDoActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_RESULT);
    }
});
```

Then, find your ListView variable:

```
ListView list = (ListView)this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Finally, add your footer view:

```
list.addFooterView(footer);
```